# No module named 'keras_tuner' even though i installed it

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, keras-tuner

i'm working on a classifier that uses CNN and i need to use the keras tuner so i can find the best CNN architecture

i executed this command "pip install keras-tuner" and it was installed successfully

but when i import it "import keras_tuner as kt" and run the python script

```
No module named 'keras_tuner'
```

i'm working offline with python 3.7.9,tensorflow 2.0,keras 2.7 in VSCode

can someone help me? i really need to use the tuner

thanks

Comment: Hello, please ensure that pip and python that you're using is the same by the commends `which python` and `which pip`. There is a chance that you're using different environments for pip and python.

Comment: thank for your reply..what do you mean ? versions?

Comment: `which` is a command-line command. Typing `which pip`  and `which python` should tell you what binary is executing. Try those commands in the terminal and share your output.

Comment: oh i see...i'm using windows not unix (i don't have which command)

Comment: Is your virtual environment active?

Comment: import sys
print(sys.prefix == sys.base_prefix) printed false so yes i'm in a venv

Comment: Given we don't know which binary is executing due to the lack of the `which` command. I would encourage you to try to install the package again. Try using `pip3` like so: `pip3 install keras-tuner`.

Comment: i have solved this and i will post the answer

Answer (score 3):

so i used

```
pip install keras_tuner
```

in VSCode and the packge was really installed but in the global site-packages folder and not in venv/lib folder

so all i did is that i went to venv/pyvenv.cfg file in VSCode

and set

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using PyCharm. When I installed the keras-tuner package in the Anaconda 3 prompt, I got the message that everything is already installed. The problem was, that the keras-tuner was installed in my base environment and not in the environment (virtual) which I use in PyCharm. You simply need to do the following.

1. check out your environments in the anaconda prompt using: `conda env list`
   you will probably see the * on the base environment
2. now change to your working environment for example `conda activate tf_cpu` -> tf_cpu needs to be changed by your envs name (see on your list)
3. install your package such as `pip install keras_tuner`